# How to hide a list in a division tag in Struts 2

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts2

```
<div id="db" style="float:left; width:50%;">
<label for="chkNewDB"><input type="checkbox" id="chkNewDB" onclick="ShowHideDivdb(this)" />Connect to a Remote Data Base</label></br></br></br>
<div><s:select label="Select a Database" headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select database" list="#{'MySQL':'MySQL', 'Microsoft SQL Server':'Microsoft SQL Server', 'Oracle':'Oracle', 'PostgreSQL':'PostgreSQL'}"    name="dbname" /><s:property value="dbname"/></div>
                    
<div id="dvHostName" style="display: none">HostName*:<s:textfield id="txtHostName" name="dbHostName"/></div></br>
                    <div id="dvPortNumber" style="display: none">Port*:<s:textfield id="txtPort" name="dbPort"/></div></br>
                    <div id="dvUserName" style="display: none">UserName*:<s:textfield id="txtUserName" name="dbUser"/></div></br>
                    <div id="dvPassword" style="display: none">Password*:<s:textfield id="txtPassword" name="dbPassword"/></div></br>
                    <s:submit value="Submit" onclick="submitDB()"/>
               <%-- </s:form>--%>
            </div>
```

I can show/hide a label and textboxes but not list and submit button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide a list

```jsp
<div style="display: none"><s:select label="Select a Database" headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select database" list="#{'MySQL':'MySQL', 'Microsoft SQL Server':'Microsoft SQL Server', 'Oracle':'Oracle', 'PostgreSQL':'PostgreSQL'}"    name="dbname" /><s:property value="dbname"/></div>
```

to hide a submit

```jsp
<div style="display: none"><s:submit value="Submit" onclick="submitDB()"/></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use div tag for Submit tag and whatever tags.

Example

```
<div id="name">
 <s:submit value="Submit" onclick="submitDB()"/>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

'Use div tag for Submit tag and whatever tags'.

and add CSS in your file.

`<div id="name">
<s:submit value="Submit" onclick="submitDB()">
</div>`;

`

## name {display:none;}

`;